# Error starting Cassandra on Mac, installed using brew

Tags: macos, cassandra

I am on OS-X El Capitan 10.11.3.
I installed Cassndra using brew and the current version is '2.2.2'

When i try to start cassandra, I get following error

```
$/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/2.2.2/bin/cassandra -f
objc[46306]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_11.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_11.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : /usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/2.2.2/libexec/jamm-0.2.5.jar
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: instrument
```

Comment: I guess you could try a hard reinstall... `brew rm cassandra --force; brew install cassandra`

Answer (score 3):

Hey this seems to be a similar problem stated in the mentioned Github post.
https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/32488

Gist from above post:

`rm -rf /usr/local/etc/cassandra/ 
brew reinstall cassandra`

But as suggested, tarball installation is simpler.

Comment: i can confirm this fixed the issue for me. going from `brew install cassandra` to `brew install cassandra22`, i guess some old configs in `/usr/local/etc` were messing with the new version.

Answer (score 1):

I never use installer (on Mac or Linux), it's so easy to download the tarball and unzip it to some folder (`/opt/apps/cassandra` for example). You'll have all your config files, binaries at the same place.

Also, do not forget to set environment variable:

```
export CASSANDRA_HOME=<your_Cassandra_install_folder>
export PATH=$PATH:$CASSANDRA_HOME/bin
```

I recommend using this method if you have trouble running Cassandra on Mac

Comment: You should not have spaces either side of the `=` sign in your `export` statements.